# Can we reduce the 3-nested summation into 2-nest summation?

Tags: summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

My problem started with the first case that I have :
$$
I_{2}=a^{k_1} (a+b)^{k_2}
$$
Where $k_1,k_2$ are real positive integers. Using the series expansion :

$$
(a+b)^n=\sum_{i_1=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i_1} a^{n-i_1} b^{i_1}
$$
Therefore,
$I_2$ can be expressed as

$$
I_2=\sum_{i_1=0}^{k_2} \binom{k_2}{i_1} a^{k_1+k_2-i_1} b^{i_1}
$$

The second case is:

$$
I_3=a^{k_1} (a+b)^{k_2} (a+b+c)^{k_3}
$$

After using the series expansion 3 times, we get

$$
I_3=\sum_{i_1=0}^{k_2} \sum_{i_2=0}^{k_3} \sum_{i_3=0}^{k_3-i_2}
\binom{k_2}{i_1}\binom{k_3}{i_2}\binom{k_3-i_2}{i_3} 
a^{k_1+k_2+k_3-i_1-i_2-i_3} 
b^{i_1+i_3} c^{i_2}
$$

My question is how can we reduce the 3-nested sum into 2-nested sum? To be more specific, I really want to express $I_3$ as 2-nested sum.

Comment: Can you express one of the variables in terms of the other two, if yes then should be able to reduce one summation

Comment: @jimjim I dont think so that we can represent a,b and c in terms of the other twos.

Comment: Then that means there are 3 independent variables, no reduction would be possible. But I don't know why it is so

Comment: @jimjim I believe there is a way to reduce the number of the summations. But how? I DONT KNOW.

Comment: Easy , the same way that a point in three dimensions can be represented with two numbers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily write $r=a+b$.

$$(r+c)^{k_3}=\sum_{m=0}^{k_3}{k_3\choose m}r^mc^{k_3-m}$$

$$r^{k_2}(r+c)^{k_3}=\sum_{m=0}^{k_3}{k_3\choose m}r^{m+k_2}c^{k_3-m}=\sum_{m=0}^{k_3}{k_3\choose m}(a+b)^{m+k_2}c^{k_3-m}$$

This is $$\sum_{m=0}^{k_3}{k_3\choose m}\sum_{n=0}^{m+k_2}{m+k_2\choose n}a^nb^{m+k_2-n}c^{k_3-m}$$ So we get $$\sum_{m=0}^{k_3}\sum_{n=0}^{m+k_2}{k_3\choose m}{m+k_2\choose n}a^{n+k_1}b^{m+k_2-n}c^{k_3-m}$$

Comment: You are great. Thanks.

Comment: I want to go further, is it possible to make it as a single sum?

Comment: I doubt it, Osama.

Comment: Or can we make it as the summation of two seprate sums. My point is to get the simpliest form of I_3.

Comment: How can two sums be simpler than one?

Comment: In my project Analysis, the sum of two seprated sums is better than one nested sum.

Comment: Still seems unlikely. If you could write it as $\sum f(n)+\sum g(n)$ then you could write it as a single sum $\sum(f(n)+g(n))$.

Comment: correct . Thanks.